# How to update data for particular id in PHP MYSQL using Android

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

**Question**

How to do changes in particular Appointment taken by User ?

**updateData.php**

```
$strUserID = $_POST["sUserID"];

/*** Update ***/
$strSQL = " UPDATE book_appointment SET
Type = '".$strType."'
,Date = '".$strDate."'
,Time = '".$strTime."'
WHERE UserID = '".$strUserID."'
";
```

Answer (score 0):

As i see it, in the update query in php:

change where clause from `UserId = 'UserId'` to `AppointmentId = 'AppointmentId' and UserId = 'UserId'`

This will update Appointment having Id as AppointmentId, and having User as UserId.

Comment: No need to have userid in that where clause

Answer (score 0):

Do this, no need for userid as each you post the correct appointment id with your request.

So this is what I would have done

```
$strAppointmentID = $_POST["AppointmentID"];
```

And then the update (Please note i do not have your exact table structure, so just modify `AppointmentID` as needed)

```
$strSQL = " UPDATE book_appointment SET
Type = '".$strType."'
,Date = '".$strDate."'
,Time = '".$strTime."'
WHERE AppointmentID = '".$strAppointmentID."'
";
```

Do note that your question is not an android problem by a SQL problem